# Wordpress $wpdb->usermeta sort by meta_value

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display all users based on a meta_key called "points" like this:

```
$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT user_id, meta_key = 'points', meta_value 
FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
ORDER BY meta_value DESC 
LIMIT $limit OFFSET {$paginate->offset()}"));
```

The users are displayed properly, but the order is not working, meta_value is equal to a number from 1 to ∞. So, how should I get it to work? Thanks.

PS: This is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 )
```

So I believe is ordered by ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT
```

**CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED)** will covert from LONGTEXT to INT. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not completely wrong about mysql, you have to add the **meta_key='points'** to the where clause.
Rewrite the query to:

> SELECT user_id, meta_value
>   FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
>   WHERE meta_key = 'points'
>   ORDER BY meta_value DESC
>   LIMIT $limit OFFSET {$paginate->offset()}

Comment: Yes, this is correct but the sort will not work, because meta_value is set to LONGTEXT so... I'm looking for a solution right now. If you know one, let me know. Thanks!